# stuck at "unresolved import" Rust Embedded

Tags: intellij-idea, rust, embedded, embedded-linux, rust-cargo

I am new to Rust and I am working in embedded development. I am making a project to blink the led of the stmf3 board. But I am getting errors while using the command `cargo build`
This [Repo](https://github.com/NitinSaxenait/Example/tree/main/blink-stm32) contains my code and structure. I am really stuck here. Can someone please a way to solve this?

The error I am getting is:

```
    error[E0433]: failed to resolve: unresolved import
 --> src/main.rs:4:12
  |
4 | use crate::config::initialization::{entry,mycrate,OutputSwitch,stm32f3xx_hal::prelude::*};
  |            ^^^^^^
  |            |
  |            unresolved import
  |            help: a similar path exists: `blink_stm32::config`

error[E0432]: unresolved imports `crate::config::initialization::entry`, `crate::config::initialization::mycrate`, `crate::config::initialization::OutputSwitch`
 --> src/main.rs:4:37
  |
4 | use crate::config::initialization::{entry,mycrate,OutputSwitch,stm32f3xx_hal::prelude::*};
  |                                     ^^^^^ ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: cannot find attribute `entry` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:6:3
  |
6 | #[entry]
  |   ^^^^^

error[E0425]: cannot find function `mycrate` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:9:29
  |
9 |     let (leds, mut delay) = mycrate();
  |                             ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
  |
help: consider importing this function
  |
4 | use blink_stm32::config::initialization::mycrate;
  |
```

Comment: Config is defined in `lib.rs` which is technically a *different* crate from `main.rs`. You have to use paths starting with crate name to use things defined in lib.rs from main.rs.

Comment: @IvanC thanks for this quick response.